# IISNode site lists folder rather than starting server.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, iis, iisnode

I am struggling to get IISNode to serve the main server.js application file for my node application by default, at the moment if I browse to http://localhost:80/ where my app is running it simply lists the folder contents of the app. Although it does run the server.js file if I click on it.

Obviously this is not working for me as the Node app is a web api which I need to be able to hit via http.

This is the line inside my web.config indicating server.js as the entry point.

Could anyone point me to something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you don't have the [URL Re-write Module for IIS](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) installed where you are running IIS.

Without URL Rewriting in your Web.config you will need to navigate to `http://localhost:80/server.js/whatever-route`. Obviously this isn't feasible in a production environment.

If you need a jump start I have a template Web.config that I use for all of my Node.js services [here](https://gist.github.com/pbaio/f63918181d8d7f8ee1d2). It has all the URL Rewriting necessary to get your app up and running and then some additional stuff (Virtual Directory Support and Socket.io Support). Just make sure that you change the main file to match the one that your app uses. The default main file in the above template Web.config is app.js. From the sounds of it you'll probably want to change this to server.js. You'll need to change [this line](https://gist.github.com/pbaio/f63918181d8d7f8ee1d2#file-gistfile1-xml-L54) and [this line](https://gist.github.com/pbaio/f63918181d8d7f8ee1d2#file-gistfile1-xml-L89). If you plan on using Socket.io you'll also need to change [this line](https://gist.github.com/pbaio/f63918181d8d7f8ee1d2#file-gistfile1-xml-L89).

Hope this helps.